# Why POST returns error even if everything is executed correctly?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, passport-local

On server side there is a following code to receive POST request:

```
router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    //console.log(res);
    passport.authenticate('signup', function(err, user, info) {
        console.log(user);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) { return res.json({redirect: 'auth'}); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err)
            {
                console.log(err);
                return next(err);
            }
            console.log(res);
            return res.json({redirect: 'userPanel'});
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

On client side the following function executes POST request and handles response:

```
$("#btn-signup").click(function() {
    var data = $('form#signupform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "/auth/signup", //process to mail
        data: data,
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log("Received data: " + msg);
            if (msg.redirect) {
                window.location.href = msg.redirect;
            }
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log("Error: " + e.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

When making a post request I get the following console output:

```
Error: {"redirect":"auth"}
```

Therefore I assume the server returns everything correctly but don't know why on client side it is considered an error.

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: It doesn't really look like you're returning JSONP, which would be wrapped in a function. You're sure the dataType shouldn't be JSON instead.

Comment: Thanks adeneo! This was the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're seeing a parse error. jQuery is expecting to see JSONP, which is JSON wrapped in a callback function, something like

```
callback({"key" : "value"});
```

but you're only returning regular JSON, as in

```
{"key" : "value"}
```

Change the dataType for jQuery from `jsonp` to just `json`

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to perform POST operations using JSONP (only GET operations). I assume you don't even need JSONP.

Instead, use JSON and change your code to

```
dataType: "json",
```